# Javascript fetch not catching error, skipping past catch statement

Tags: javascript, http, promise, try-catch, fetch

I'm sending HTTP-requests to a server and when I receive them, I check for the status. If the status isn't 200, I want to throw the response of the server and catch it to do stuff with the error.

```js
const handleRegistration = (nickname, email, password) => {
    fetch("https://localhost:44317/api/Authentication/register",
        {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({nickname: nickname, email: email, password: password}),
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                location.href = "../login/login.html";
            } else {
                throw response.json();
            }
        })
        .catch((response) => {
            // Do something
        });
};
```

When I register a new account where all the input fields are valid, the program works fine. But when I input data that makes for the server to return a 400 POST with as Response {"DuplicateUserName":["User name 'blabla' is already taken."]}, then I get TypeError: handleFetch(...) is undefined in my console. I'm not really sure what to do.

I've set breakpoints in the catch statement and noticed that my code never reaches it.

Comment: It's not clear why `handleFetch()` is defined twice. One thing that's pretty clear is that `handleFetch()` should return the Promise that `fetch()` returns.

Comment: The handleFetch being defined twice is my mad. I messed up. 
And what do you mean by handleFetch() needing to return the Promise? Isn't that what is already happening right now?

Comment: No, your `handleFetch()` function has no `return` statement. It *calls* fetch but does not return the returned Promise.

Comment: What about return response.json()

Comment: That's *inside* the `.then()` callback. You need `return fetch(...).then(...)`

Comment: I've modified the code to more so focus on the issue I'm having.